# On the set of non-zero reals, if the derivatives are equal, do they differ by a constant?

Tags: real-analysis

On the set of non-zero reals, if the derivatives are equal, do they differ by a constant? I am looking for a counterexample: let D be a set of non-zero reals, $$f(x)=\begin {cases} -2, x \in (-\infty,0) \\ 2, x\in (0,\infty), 
\end{cases}$$
and $g(x)=0$ on D. Then $f'=g'=0$ on D, however f and g do not differ by a constant. So because D is not an interval f and g do not differ by a constant, right?

I want to generalize: if D is not connected, f and g do not differ by a constant. Am I correct?

Comment: You are correct in all areas, yes, and essentially the same argument will work for your generalisation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ be an interval with endpoints and assume $f$ and $g$ are differentiabe on $D$ and $f'=g'$. Fix some $a\in D$ Then, using the fundamental theorem of calculus, you get

$$f(x)-f(a)= \int_{a}^xf'=\int_{a}^xg'=g(x)-g(a)$$

So you get, $$f(x)= g(x) + (f(a)-g(a)),$$ for any $x\in D$. Since $f(a)-g(a)$ is constant, you get your result.